# Why does a positive WPF XAML CenterX value move the element left?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just learning WPF and confused by the way CenterX and Center Y operate.  I'm sure it's just my perspective but I can't figure it out.

(The XAML below has unnecessary properties only to make it easier to see/emphasize the changes between the buttons.)

```
    <StackPanel Width=" 100" >

        <Button Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" >
            <Button.RenderTransform >
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX ="1" ScaleY ="1" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform> normal
        </Button>

        <Button Background="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" >
            <Button.RenderTransform >
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX =" 2"  ScaleY ="1" CenterX="5" CenterY="0"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform> normal
        </Button>

        <Button Background ="Yellow" >
            <Button.RenderTransform >
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX =" 2" ScaleY =" 2" CenterX="0" CenterY="5"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform> normal
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
```

2nd Button: CenterX to a positive 5, it moves left.

3rd Button: CenterY to a positive 5, it moves up.

I understand why the 3rd button goes up; Y is a positive value

Why does the 2nd button go left; X is a positive value, but left seems a negative direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" CenterX="5"/>
```

scales the Button horizontally by a factor of `2`, with `(5,0)` as the center point of the scaling transform.

When the Button has a width of 100 before the transform, it becomes 200 units wide afterwards. Since the scaling is made at a `CenterX` value of 5, before the transform there were 5 units to the left of the center and 95 to the right.

After scaling, it becomes 10 units to the left and 190 to right. So effectively, it has moved 5 units to the left.

Comment: That makes sense, but even before the scaling you said, correctly, it is "5 units to the left"; that's my sticking point. Why does a positive CenterX move left?  In coordinate planes a positive value moves right.  I'm beginning to think it's simply an arbitrary decision that 'positive moves left'; which is OK, just not intuitive. I just hoped someone might have insight to the reason positive X moves in a negative direction. The same thing happens with Skew AngleX; a position AngleX skews counterclockwise, the opposite expected from geometry.

Comment: It isn't moved before the scaling (it just has 5 units left of the transform center at x=5, i.e. +5 -5 = 0). Play around with different CenterX values, or with different values for the Button's `RenderTransformOrigin` property, which defines the transform center in relative coordinates. E.g, (0.5, 0.5) scales around the center of the element.